# Для сокращения кода нужно из третьего метода nt weekdayCount вызвать второй weekendCount. Как это переделать, подскажите пожалуйста!

Tags: java, рефакторинг

Реализуй три метода:

- boolean isWeekend(String dayName) - метод принимает строку и отвечает, является ли данная строка выходным днем. Выходным днем являются Sunday и Saturday.
- int weekendCount(String[] days) - метод принимает массив строк и возвращает количество выходных дней в этом массиве.
- int weekdayCount(String[] days) - метод принимает массив строк и возвращает количество будних дней в этом массиве.

Требования:

- методы должны быть public static
- сигнатура метода isWeekend(String dayName)
- метод возвращает boolean
- сигнатура метода weekendCount(String[] days)
- метод возвращает int
- сигнатура метода weekdayCount(String[] days)
- метод возвращает int
- переиспользовать методы, не копировать код

  ```
  public static boolean isWeekend(String dayName) {
       return (dayName.equalsIgnoreCase("Sunday") || dayName.equalsIgnoreCase("Saturday")); 
   }
   public static int weekendCount(String[] days) {
       int weekend = 0;
       for (String day : days) {
           if (isWeekend(day)) {
               weekend++;
           }
       }
       return weekend;
   }

   public static int weekdayCount(String[] days) {
       int weekday = 0;
       for (String day : days) {
           if (!isWeekend(day)) {
               weekday++;
           }
       }
       return weekday;
   }
  ```

Comment: weekdayCount = days.size - weekendCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть в массиве всего N дней. День может быть либо выходным, либо рабочим. Соответственно, если в массиве M выходных дней, то рабочих дней в нём:

```
N - M
```

Значит, третий метод, считающий количество рабочих дней, можно переписать следующим образом:

```
public static int weekdayCount(String[] days) {
   return days.length - weekendCount(days);
   //          N      -         M           = количество рабочих дней
}
```

При этом метод, считающий количество выходных дней, можно немного упростить с использованием Stream API:

```
public static int weekendCount(String[] days) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(days)
            .filter(Main::isWeekend)
            .count();
}
// где Main - имя класса, в котором находится статический метод isWeekend. Имя класса может быть любым.
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, очень помог!!!

Comment: @GalaArbatskaya в качестве "спасибо" на stackoverflow служит галочка)